# Laravel - Eager loaded model function

Tags: php, laravel, api, relationship, eager

I am trying to build some chat system using Laravel and i have these 2 models: User and Thread

The User model has Messagable Trait where you can get all the threads with

```
$user->threads();
```

I am trying to eager load additional data to the threads array using the following:

```
$threads = Auth::user()->threads()->with(['participants.user'])->get();
```

What i am struggling is the Threads model has function to get the latest message from it:

```
$thread->getLatestMessage();
```

My question is how can i append this latest message to the upper query i am doing. I was trying something like this but its not ok... I guess im doing something stupid here...

```
$threads = Auth::user()->threads()->with([
        'participants.user',
        'latestMessage' => function ($query) {
            return $query->getLatestMessageAttribute();
        }])->get();
```

or

```
$threads = Auth::user()->threads()->with(['participants.user','getLatestMessageAttribute'])->get();
```

I hope i clarified this ok because i am using a 3rd party package for this system which has these Traits and Thread classes i am using.

**SOLUTION**

Looks like i had to add append('accessor_name') at the end when getting the collection.

```
$collection = Auth::user()->relationship()->get()->append('accessor_name');
```

Comment: try adding   protected $appends=['latest_message']; in thread model

Comment: I was thinking of that too ... but the problem is the Thread model comes from a package vendor. How can i modify that or override the Thread model with my own one

Comment: can you mention package link

Comment: https://github.com/lexxyungcarter/laravel-5-messenger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  can override class .Create new model and extend package model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;


class Thread extends \Lexx\ChatMessenger\Models\Thread
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $appends=['latest_message'];
    

}
```

Publish config:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Lexx\ChatMessenger\ChatMessengerServiceProvider" --tag="config"
```

in **config/chatmessenger.php**

```
'thread_model' => \App\Models\Thread::class,
```

**Updated**
If anyone still not getting get attribute data then dont forget to clear cache

```
php artisan cache:clear

php artisan optimize

php artisan config:clear

php artisan clear
```

Comment: I did this and now when i try doing the following... The latest_message is not inside the object

Auth::user()->threads()->with(['participants.user'])->get();

Comment: it might not in object but try accessing that object.Also try  public function getLatestMessageAttribute()
    {
        return $this->messages()->latest()->first();
    } this method in new model

Comment: @NenadKaevik.if you are using laravel 8 then update    'user_model' => App\Models\User::class,

Comment: Did all of this and i still cannot see the latest_message column in the response object

Comment: instead of dd($thread) .try once accessing dd($thread->latest_message)

Comment: @NenadKaevik  if that doesn't work then create your own accessor  new model and try whether it will append to objecy

Comment: last option i can create new method  public function latestMessage()
    {
        return $this->messages()->latest()->first();
    } and access like $thread->latestMessage();

Comment: For gods sake man this pissed me off... This is how i solved it ...
$threads = Auth::user()->threads()->with('participants.user','messages')->get()->append('latest_message');

I had to call append('accessor') after getting the collection ...

Comment: oops but i really didnt know why it doesn't work .i dont have pusher account or else i would have given one try

Comment: That was weird though ... It was supposed to work like you mentioned above... I got no idea tbh... Anyways man ... appreciate your help :D Finally got this figured out ... Thanks a TON! 

Comment: @NenadKaevik.add your sollution in answer and accept your answer as accepted.so it help someone to solve.

Comment: @NenadKaevik. i have tried using appends it works well https://ibb.co/ydjNNPz   ....try clearing cache or run php artisan optimize

Comment: Omg... true ... Stupid cache -_-